# Open Source Licenses Question

Tags: open-source, licensing

I am in the process of making a webpage in the pyramid framework (python) and I am going to make it opensource so that people can add to it, take from it, learn from it, etc.

But I don't want them to just take the code and not accredit my friends and I for writing the code they are using. I was wondering how to go about getting a license like that?

I looked up the GNU Free Documentation License, but I couldn't find how I would get that license or implement it.

Comment: take a look : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/82035/which-open-source-license-is-right-for-my-project/82059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See link at bottom of page http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

> blog content and podcasts are licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 United States License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/).

Linked page, in turn, explains terms there as follows:

> This is a human-readable summary of the **[Legal Code (the full license)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/legalcode)**.